# How to find and replace every even-numbered appearance of a match in BASH?

Tags: perl, bash, replace, sed, awk

I am using `sed -i 's/AAA/ZZZ/g' filename` to replace every occurance of "AAA" with "ZZZ" in a file. I need to instead replace every even-numbered appearance of "AAA" with "ZZZ", e.g.:

```
This is a AAA sentence. AAA
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet AAA another AAA sentence.
This is AAA stillAAA AAA yet AAA another AAA sentence.
```

This would become:

```
This is a AAA sentence. ZZZ
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet ZZZ another AAA sentence.
This is ZZZ stillAAA ZZZ yet AAA another ZZZ sentence.
```

How to replace every even-numbered appearance of a match?

Comment: I think you mean every other appearance (odd number). Because you are replacing the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc.

Comment: ^^ No, OP is replacing even numbered occurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short gnu `awk` version

```
awk '{ORS=NR%2==0?"ZZZ":RS}1' RS="AAA" file
This is a AAA sentence. ZZZ
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet ZZZ another AAA sentence.
This is ZZZ stillAAA ZZZ yet AAA another ZZZ sentence.
```

Comment: I was trying exactly this (after reading @anubhava's answer). Looks like I made some errors & could not make it work :-(
+1

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is better tool for this than `sed`. Consider this awk command:

```
awk -F 'AAA' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {OFS=c%2?"ZZZ":FS; printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; c++}
    print $NF}' file
This is a AAA sentence. ZZZ
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet ZZZ another AAA sentence.
This is ZZZ stillAAA ZZZ yet AAA another ZZZ sentence.
```

This awk sets the input field separator as `AAA` and and toggles output field separator between `AAA` and `ZZZ` depending upon a counter is odd or even. Every time counter is even OFS is set to `AAA` and when it is odd OFS is set to `ZZZ`

Comment: @anishsane If you play with `RS` and `ORS` you can get a relay short `awk`, see my post

Comment: This can be shorten some: `awk -F 'AAA' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {OFS=c%2?"ZZZ":FS;printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; c++} print $NF}'`

Comment: @Jotne: Good point, yes it be shortened like this, let me edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perl solution:

```
$ cat inp
This is a AAA sentence. AAA
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet AAA another AAA sentence.
This is AAA stillAAA AAA yet AAA another AAA sentence.

$ perl -pe 'my $line = "" ; while(<>){ $line=$line.$_} $line =~ s/(.*?AAA.*?)AAA/\1ZZZ/mgs; print $line;' < inp
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet ZZZ another AAA sentence.
This is ZZZ stillAAA ZZZ yet AAA another ZZZ sentence.
```

Here, first I accumulate entire file in a variable `$line`. & Then, I replace every alternate occurrence of AAA with ZZZ; using non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 2):

Perl:

```
perl -wpe 'BEGIN{$/="AAA"} $.%2 or s/AAA/ZZZ/' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` too:

```
sed -n -e '1,$ { 
:oddline  s/AAA/\n/g; :odd  s/\n/AAA/m; t even ;p;N;s/.*\n//;b oddline ; 
:evenline s/AAA/\n/g; :even s/\n/ZZZ/m; t odd ; p;N;s/.*\n//;b evenline ; 
}' << _END_
This is a AAA sentence. AAA
This is another AAA sentence.
This is yet AAA another AAA sentence.
This is AAA stillAAA AAA yet AAA another AAA sentence.
_END_
```

The sed script loops through all lines and remembers odd/even replacements (across lines). In the pattern space, all AAAs are first replaced by newlines and then replaced one at a time by either AAA or ZZZ. In order to switch to the next line it is first appended (`N`) and then the previous one is deleted (`s/.*\n//`).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};/\x00/q1;s/AAA/\x00/g;s/(\x00)([^\x00]*)\1/AAA\2ZZZ/g' file
```

This slurps the file into memory and then replaces all occurences of `AAA` with a unique character. Then every odd and even occurence of the unique character is replaced by `AAA` and `ZZZ` respectively.

N.B. If the `unique character` is not unique, no change is made to the file and an error code of `1` is set.

This second method is more long-winded but can be used to change the N'th value and does not rely on an `unique value`:

```
sed  -r 's/AAA/\n&/g;/\n/!b;G;:a;s/$/#/;s/#{2}$//;/\n$/s/\nAAA/\nZZZ/;s/\n//;/\n.*\n/ba;P;s/^.*\n//;h;d' file
```

It stores the number of occurences of the required pattern in the hold space and retrieves it when encounters a line with such a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "1 h;1 !H;$ {x;l;s/=/=e/g;s/²/=c/g;s/AAA/²/g;s/²\([^²]\{1,\}\)²/²\1ZZZ/g;s/²/AAA/g;s/=c/²/g;s/=e/=/g;}" YourFile
```

Using substitution (due to AAA that could be inside a .*) insurring that even with substitute char is inside it work with the double translation before and after

Comment: What is your meaning of "AA that could be inside a .*"?

Comment: sed have the limitation about "not" and because it take the biggest pattern available a regex 'AAA.*AAA' on AAA blabla AAA blibli AAA blublu AAA take the whole string and not the first peer. To avoid that I change AAA to a single char (²) and use an expression of kind '²[^²]*²' so it take only first peer